# Meteor not simulating properly on iOS

Tags: meteor, ionic-framework, ios-simulator, angular-meteor

I am currently working on developing an app using Meteor. I would like to use Meteor with the Ionic Framework.

When trying out this tutorial :
https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp/meteor/bootstrapping

I noticed that the web-simulation on localhost works like a charm, but when I try the following command : `meteor run ios`, a lot of graphical elements aren't showing. For example, the icons in the footer (menu-bar) don't show.

When I was doing *regular* Ionic development, the simulator perfectly rendered all the implemented elements.

Does anyone know how to fix the problem ? (Packages to install maybe ?)

Cheers !

Comment: Does it render ok in the Chrome browser? and Safari? - If the problem is the same in Safari, it means that there is something wrong with the html or css that is being generated, or something missing

Comment: It's fine in both Chrome and Safari. Only the iOS Simulator doesn't show some information.

Comment: Run up the safari inspector and see if there are console errors. You can also inspect the elements to try and work out what has happened

Comment: That's the thing : no errors, everything works fine on `localhost`, but none of the icons show up on the iOS simulator ..